# What's the difference between flow based and block based visual programming. Are there any more alternative?

Tags: flowchart, unreal-blueprint, blockly, visual-programming

As far as I can see there was 2 dominance paradigms of visual programming. One is node and flow based like in game engine such as unreal/unity or media applicatoin such as blender and so on. Then there are block based like blockly and similarly variant

Makes me wonder are there any more style of visual programming distinct from these. And what exactly difference that make them more preferable in which situation. Why game engine not use block based? Is the block based are simpler to use for kid?

I can't find a good comparison explanation with my google capability. Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both node and flow based and block based programming have their advantages and disadvantages, depends on the context.

Node and flow based:

- more flexible and powerful, allowing for complex data processing and control flow.

Block based:

- more intuitive and accessible, especially for beginners or children who may not be familiar with traditional text-based programming.

Most game engines use node and flow based because they require a lot of control over the underlying systems, such as physics, animation, and AI. Block based programming may be simpler to use for children, but it may not be as effective for complex game logic.